# Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined cloudinary

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am having this error

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type
> string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Object

but I dont know how to solve it:

Here is my code base:

```
router.post('/upload/image', fileUpload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
  let streamUpload = (req) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
        (error, result) => {
          if (result) {
            resolve(result);
          } else {
            reject(error);
          }
        }
      );
      console.log("Images ", req.files);  
      streamifier.createReadStream(req.files.buffer).pipe(stream);
    }).
      catch(error => { throw error; });
  };
  
  async function upload(req) {
      let result = await streamUpload(req);
      console.log(result);
  }
  
  upload(req);
});
```

Thank you anyone who help me solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

As you're using `fileUpload.single('file'),` you should use `req.file` not `req.files`

Note `req.file.buffer` is only available with `memorystorage`

```
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
cont upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#memorystorage

```
console.log("Images ", req.file);  
streamifier.createReadStream(req.file.buffer).pipe(stream);
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: If i change it to `req.file` I end up have this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined`

Comment: @NathanNguyen Are you using memoryStorage? `const storage = multer.memoryStorage()` . What does `req.file` logs on console ?

Comment: @NathanNguyen https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#memorystorage

Answer (score 0):

`cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream` expects 2 parameters, first should be `string | buffer` and second should be a `callback object (error, result)`.

You are passing `(error, result)` as the only parameter, I believe that's what causing the error.

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream('YOUR BUFFER OR STRING HERE', (error, result)=>{})
```

Comment: How can I know what is my buffer or string in this case ?

Comment: I believe it would be the file you are trying to upload- name of it. Not 100% sure as I never worked with this, but by the looks it seems right.